# mysql update with filter by json selection

Tags: mysql

This sql statement works

```
SELECT * FROM form_submission WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(json_data, "$.startup") = "test company"
```

but when use for update

```
UPDATE form_submission SET status='submit' WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(json_data, "$.startup") = "test company"
```

will return error of

"Syntax error in JSON text in argument 1 to function 'json_extract' at position 617"

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some functions, including json_extract, result in an error when encountering bad data only when used in a data modification statement such as UPDATE.  You can prevent it in the case by checking if json_data is valid before extracting:

```
UPDATE form_submission SET status='submit' WHERE JSON_VALID(json_data) AND JSON_EXTRACT(json_data, "$.startup") = "test company";
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c4f86c20222e087e480b885243b68e13)